# Exchange 2010 Resources auto-accept

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, resources

In my Exchange 2010 set up I have all my conference rooms configured as resources and to auto accept non-conflicting requests. All the resources have been scheduling correctly until Monday. The only thing that changed from last week was patching the server with windows update. Now the resources will not auto-book the room and because it's not auto-accepting it's not sending an e-mail to the meeting organizer saying the room has been booked. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall any recent Exchange patches one at a time, and see if that resolves it. If it does, call Microsoft for free support on patches.